# Error while building project in QT

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to work in ROS with QTCreator. I have to packages A and B in ros workspace. its location is /home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox/A and /home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox/B.

my environment variables are

```
 declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY="/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros"
 declare -x ROS_DISTRO="fuerte"
 declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros"
 declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
 declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/it/Desktop/gps/sandbox/gps_sub:/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros"
 declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros"
 declare -x ROS_WORKSPACE="/home/it/Desktop/rosspace"
```

I have written this to ./bashrc

```
 source /home/mit/Desktop/rosspace/setup.bash 
 export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

I opened QTCreator from terminal.

then open file or project->/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox/A/cmakelist.text

after choosing qt build directory and running cmake

i got following error:

```
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:99 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "A" at "", but the
  current directory is
  "/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox/A".  You should
  double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the
  correct precedence order.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177(_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


  [rosbuild] Building package A
```

please help me to open my project in QT

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, QTCreator latest version and ROS-Fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106296/error-while-building-project-in-qt/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that there's a problem due to multiple includes of your sandbox directory in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You're doing this:

```
 declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/it/Desktop/gps/sandbox/gps_sub:/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros"
```

then

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

The only thing you need to do is this:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/it/Desktop/rosspace/sandbox:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

Are you also sourcing the /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash script or do you have your own in /home/mit/Desktop/rosspace/setup.bash? I suggest you simplify things by sourcing 1 script and doing either declarations or exports of your variables, not both as you're currently doing for ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0